# URL to URI encoding changes a "%3D" to "%253D"

Tags: java, url, encoding, uri

I'm having trouble encoding a URL to a URI:

```
mUrl = "A string url that needs to be encoded for use in a new HttpGet()";
URL url = new URL(mUrl);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), 
    url.getQuery(), null);
```

This does not do what I expect for the following URL:

**Passing in the String:**

http://m.bloomingdales.com/img?url=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.bloomingdales.com%2Fis%2Fimage%2FBLM%2Fproducts%2F3%2Foptimized%2F1140443_fpx.tif%3Fwid%3D52%26qlt%3D90%2C0%26layer%3Dcomp%26op_sharpen%3D0%26resMode%3Dsharp2%26op_usm%3D0.7%2C1.0%2C0.5%2C0%26fmt%3Djpeg&ttl=30d

**Comes out as:**

http://m.bloomingdales.com/img?url=http%253A%252F%252Fimages.bloomingdales.com%252Fis%252Fimage%252FBLM%252Fproducts%252F3%252Foptimized%252F1140443_fpx.tif%253Fwid%253D52%2526qlt%253D90%252C0%2526layer%253Dcomp%2526op_sharpen%253D0%2526resMode%253Dsharp2%2526op_usm%253D0.7%252C1.0%252C0.5%252C0%2526fmt%253Djpeg&ttl=30d

Which is broken.  For example, the `%3D` is turned into `%253D` It seems to be doing something mysterious to the %'s already in the string.

What's going on and what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are first putting the (already-escaped) string into the `URL` class. That doesn't escape anything. Then you are pulling out sections of the `URL`, which returns them without any further processing (so -- they are still escaped since they were escaped when you put them in). Finally, you are putting the sections into the `URI` class, using the [multi-argument constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). This constructor is specified as encoding the URI components using percentages.

Therefore, it is in this final step that, for example, "`:`" becomes "`%3A`" (good) and "`%3A`" becomes "`%253A`" (bad). Since you are putting in URLs which are already-encoded*, you don't want to encode them again.

Therefore, the [single-argument constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String%29) of `URI` is your friend. It doesn't escape anything, and requires that you pass a pre-escaped string. Hence, you don't need `URL` at all:

```
mUrl = "A string url is already percent-encoded for use in a new HttpGet()";
URI uri = new URI(mUrl);
```

*The only problem is if your URLs are sometimes not percent-encoded, and sometimes they are. Then you have a bigger problem. You need to decide whether your program is starting out with a URL which is always encoded, or one which needs to be encoded.

Note that there is *no such thing* as a full URL which is not percent-encoded. For example, you can't take the full URL "`http://example.com/bob&co`" and somehow turn it into the properly-encoded URL "`http://example.com/bob%26co`" -- how can you tell the difference between the syntax (which shouldn't be escaped) and the characters (which should)? This is why the single-argument form of `URI` requires that strings are already-escaped. If you have unescaped strings, you need to percent-encode them *before* inserting them into the full URL syntax, and that is what the multi-argument constructor of `URI` helps you do.

**Edit:** I missed the fact that the original code discards the fragment. If you want to remove the fragment (or any other part) of the URL, you can construct the `URI` as above, then pull all the parts out as required (they will be *decoded* into regular strings), then pass them back into the `URI` multi-argument constructor (where they will be *re-encoded* as URI components):

```
uri = new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(),
              uri.getPath(), uri.getQuery(), null)  // Remove fragment
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the write up.  The urls are being pulled from html code, so I assume they would have to be encoded already then?   One of the reasons I was using the URL and the multi-argument constructor was because I needed to remove the fragment (if any) from the URI.  Is there a way I can do this without forcing the double encoding?  Would something like String urlMinusFragment = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority() + url.getPath() + "?" + url.getQuery();  Be safe to do?  Then I could throw that string into the new URI(string) constructor.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you are ripping URLs out of, say, the `href` property in HTML, then they should always be properly-encoded (if they aren't, then the HTML is invalid, so you could treat it as an error). The technique for removing the fragment seems OK but you are manually constructing a URL (which there is a library for). I would use the URI class. Like URL, URI has component getters, but they return *decoded* strings which are safe to put back into URI. So `URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), uri.getPath(), uri.getQuery(), null)` should work.

Answer (score 6):

**%3d** means-> **=** *(Equal)*

And

**%253D** --> **=** *(Equal)*  decimal 6hex (byte) 3D

**%253D** hex indicator 
for CGI: **%3D**

Comment: %3d in UTF-8 format? How can we decode String with %3D, %26 etc characters?

Answer (score 4):

**The `URL` class didn't decode the %-sequences when it parsed the URL, but the `URI` class is encoding them (again).  Use `URI` to parse the URL string.**

Javadocs:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

> ***The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components*** according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields, that are returned from URL. Furthermore, because URL has no knowledge of URL escaping, it does not recognise equivalence between the encoded or decoded form of the same URL. For example, the two URLs:

```
http://foo.com/hello world/ and http://foo.com/hello%20world
```

> would be considered not equal to each other.
>   Note, the URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in certain circumstances.
>
> ***The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use URI***, and to convert between these two classes using toURI() and URI.toURL().

Answer (score -2):

What is happening here is that the `%` signs from the first URL are being escaped, meaning they are turned into `%25` in the output.  You need to put precautions in place so that your script only escapes alphanumeric characters, as well as some symbols — but *not* already escaped characters.

These are some characters that NEED escaping:

```
<
>
"
!
#
$
'
(
)
*
,
-
.
/
:
;
@
[
\
]
^
_
`
{
|
}
~
```

The rest, like `=`, `%`, and `&`, and alphanumeric characters, do not.

Comment: No, that isn't the right way to think about it at all. You already have a complete percent-encoded URL. Every character that already needs to be encoded is encoded. If your advice is not to encode the "%" signs, well sure, "%3A" will stay as "%3A" instead of becoming "%253A", but you will also be over-encoding other syntactic elements. For example, "x=4&y=7" (meaning x is "4" and y is "7") will become "x=4%26y=7" (meaning x is "4&y=7"). Trying to get the exact right set of characters means more common cases will work, and you'll have fewer buggy edge cases, but you won't eliminate them.

Comment: Also, you have listed "=" and "%" as both needing escaping, and not needing escaping.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those errors out.  My impression of what was wrong with littleFluffyKitty's code was that some characters were double-encoded.

Comment: From RFC3986: "URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that component." in the a path segment for example the ':' is allowed