# sonar-scanner-maven fails on branch build

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I tried a branch build on an empty pom.

```
$ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.corp.tld  -Dsonar.login=5846e53_LOGIN_HASH_d7e04e819  -Dsonar.projectKey=out.projectkey -Dsonar.branch.name=apple
```

And I got this error:

```
Parameter 'characteristic' must be a key-value pair with the format 'key=value'.
```

From maven DEBUG logs, I see:

```
[DEBUG] 21:45:02.528 Upload report
[DEBUG] 21:45:03.459 POST 400 https://sonar.copr.tld/api/ce/submit?projectKey=our.projectkey&projectName=projName&characteristic=branch%253Dapple&characteristic=branchType%253DSHORT | time=928ms
```

On the SonarQube server side, in log we can see:

```
172.16.0.14 - - [06/Jul/2018:19:03:42 +0200] "POST /api/ce/submit?projectKey=our.projectkey&projectName=projName&characteristic=branch%253Dapple&characteristic=branchType%253DSHORT HTTP/1.1" 400 103 "-" "ScannerMaven/3.4.1.1168/3.5.0" "SERVER_ID"
```

Sonar server: 7.1

Maven version 3.5.4

And i also tried the newst sonar maven plugin.

We discovered, the problem seems, the double encoded `branch` and `branchType` of `characteristics` URL param.

Is there anybody who met same like that?

Thanks,
zsolt

Comment: It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858108/url-to-uri-encoding-changes-a-3d-to-253d). Did you use any 'special' characters?

Comment: no, not really.
The brach name was really: `apple`
the `project.key` and the domain also not using any special character.
It think is reproducable anybody, who would like to use sonar analyzes from maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

Background info:
Our sonar server work behind httpS and the apache redirects all reuqest from `http` to `https`.

So, the good maven call is:

`$ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.corp.tld  -Dsonar.login=5846e53_LOGIN_HASH_d7e04e819  -Dsonar.projectKey=out.projectkey -Dsonar.branch.name=apple`

the difference is
`-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.corp.tld`

Answer (score 2):

For us the same error occured when setting sonar.branch.name to an empty value. If this property is missing, everything is ok. But when it is empty, the request will contain a parameter branch= (nothing) and this is, what the characteristics error message is complaining about, because it is just key= (nothing) and not key=value.