# Clicking on hyperlink in Excel is adding 25's to the hyperlink address?

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011. When inserting a hyperlink (right click -> Edit hyperlink) Excel is converting all the %20 in the link address to blank spaces. An example of this:
Correct format / path of link to the page:
http://MyFictionalSite.com/nfl/query?sdql=team%20%3D%20Bears%20and%20p%3AD%20and%20DIV%20and%20p%3ARY%20%3C%20pp%3ARY%20%3C%20ppp%3ARY%20and%20season%20%3E%3D%201996

What Excel turns my hyperlink address into:
http://MyFictionalSite.com/nfl/query?sdql=team %3D Bears and p%3AD and DIV and p%3ARY %3C pp%3ARY %3C ppp%3ARY and season %3E%3D 1996

If I copy and paste either of these links directly into the browser they will both actually work fine. This issue is when I click on the hyperlink in Excel the link converts to:
http://MyFictionalSite.com/nfl/query?sdql=team%20%253D%20Bears%20and%20p%253AD%20and%20DIV%20and%20p%253ARY%20%253C%20pp%253ARY%20%253C%20ppp%253ARY%20and%20season%20%253E%253D%201996

Why are these "25's" being added only when clicking on the excel hyperlink? How can this be fixed?
There are over 100 links in one column like this I need to convert.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858108/url-to-uri-encoding-changes-a-3d-to-253d    have you done a search and bypassed this?

Comment: @donPablo Not sure how Javascript applies in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this only applies to this particular version of Excel 2011 for Mac. But if you replace all the "%20" or " " (blank spaces) with "+" the hyperlinks work as they should.

```
Sub changepath()
' Select a range or column first.
    Dim HyperLinkCount As Long
    For HyperLinkCount = 1 To Selection.Hyperlinks.Count
        Selection.Hyperlinks(HyperLinkCount).Address = Replace(Selection.Hyperlinks(HyperLinkCount).Address, " ", "+")
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The %25 is the encoding character for the percentage symbols (%) in your string.

You may be able to fix this by setting a different browser as default and that may handle it better.  Alternately we could go back to your original question to see if we can escape it out.

See the following page for a more detailed description:

https://searchmarketingcorner.wordpress.com/tag/excel-formulas/

**Original issue:**
I can't reproduce your original issue on my version of Excel, but we can verify if the functions are the same.

Let's try this (note that you have to have the hyperlinks selected to run, or it does nothing):

```
Sub changepath()
' Select a range or column first.
    Dim HyperLinkCount As Long
    For HyperLinkCount = 1 To Selection.Hyperlinks.Count
        Selection.Hyperlinks(HyperLinkCount).Address = Replace(Selection.Hyperlinks(HyperLinkCount).Address, " ", "%20")
        Selection.Hyperlinks(HyperLinkCount).TextToDisplay = Replace(Selection.Hyperlinks(HyperLinkCount).Address, "%20", " ")
    Next
End Sub
```

The loop uses a nice excel function "Selection.Hyperlinks.Count" to iterate through the possible hyperlinks.

Then I've just translated what I think you wanted into what gave me that output.

I found some of this from this forum page:

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/99473-vba-hyperlink-text-to-display

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried every browser I have. The macro you provided, although helpful, will not help in this case because blank space isn't the issue. As you stated it is the % encoding.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, I wasn't expecting the + symbol to be the solution at the point where other characters were being encoded.